# react-native: Fade ScrollView bottom

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to implement a `ScrollView` list that fades out the bottom items in the list. This is achievable by monitoring the scroll position, determining the layout of each item and then adding opacity to each item ~ Even then, it won't achieve a smooth fade as each item will have a fixed opacity.

I'm wondering if there is a more graceful and cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: I am interested to that too. Did you find any other solution outside of here? I am not sure how to do this too.

Answer (score 8):

1. Use LinearGradient from expo to render a smooth fadeout.
2. If ScrollView has touchable item, add prop 'pointerEvents={'none'}' to LinearGradient. It can bypass touch events to ScrollView.

   ```
   import {LinearGradient} from 'expo';

   <View style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
     <ScrollView />
     <LinearGradient
       style={{position:'absolute', bottom:0, width:100, height:20}}
       colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)']}
       pointerEvents={'none'}
     />
   </View>
   ```

edit:

3. If it is dynamic images, maybe you can try the backgroundColor of image's parent. The following example is black, so use black LinearGradient.

   ```
   <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
     <ImageBackground
       style={{flex:1}}
       source={{uri:'https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beauty-bloom-blue-67636.jpg&fm=jpg'}}
     >
       <LinearGradient
         style={{flex:1}}
         locations={[0.7, 0.9, 1]}
         colors={['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)']}
         pointerEvents={'none'}
       />
     </ImageBackground>
   </View>
   ```

Comment: A beautiful hack for apps that use a solid color as a background. Won't work with dynamic backgrounds like images etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is package for achieving fade effects in `ScrollView`.

[rn-faded-scrollview](https://github.com/mak12/rn-faded-scrollview) does work good.

```
 <RNFadedScrollView
    allowStartFade={true}
    allowEndFade={true}
    bounces={false}
    horizontal={true}
     >
 </RNFadedScrollView>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fadingedgelength" prop (Android only)
https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/scrollview#fadingedgelength